# Can't mount read-write iSCSI with MTU=9000

Tags: filesystems, mount, iscsi, mtu, jumboframes

I'm attempting to connect my desktop (running debian 7) to a QNAP NAS (running QTS 4.1.1) using iSCSI with an MTU=9000. The network infrastructure consists of a cat5e crossover cable between the desktop and the nas.

If I set the MTU on local machine and iSCSI machine to either 1500, 4074, or 7418 everything works fine.

However, if I set MTU to 9000 and issue the same `mount` command as before then it mounts as a read only filesystem:

```
mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/iscsi
```

After that command is issued, the output of `mount -l` is:

```
/dev/sdc1 on /mnt/iscsi type ext4 (rw,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered)
```

However as soon as I try to write to the filesystem I receive an error `Read-only file system` and the output of `mount -l` becomes:

```
/dev/sdc1 on /mnt/iscsi type ext4 (ro,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered)
```

I've tried mounting with `-w` and `-o rw` but neither have any effect. Does anyone have any suggestions on what might be causing this?

I know the nas supports jumbo frames, but could it be that the NIC doesn't support them? Is there any way to check?

Comment: Do you have a switch between your machines ? Is it supports Jumbo frames ?

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned that - I'm using a crossover cable

Comment: Just don't use jumbo frames...

Comment: If at first you don't succeed 'n all?